# Bound Mismatch Error

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to add an attribute "Collection" to display on the front Office of hybris B2C Accelerator.

So far I have declared the following Beans in my projectName-Spring.xml file:

```
<alias name="defaultProductSpecialPopulator" alias="productSpecialPopulator" />
    <bean id="defaultProductSpecialPopulator" class="de.hybris.electronics.facades.populators.ProductSpecialPopulator" scope="prototype">
        <property name="modelService" ref="modelService" />
    </bean>

    <alias name="defaultProductConfiguredPopulator" alias="productConfiguredPopulator" />
    <bean id="defaultProductConfiguredPopulator" class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator">
        <property name="populators">
            <map key-type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.ProductOption">
                <entry key="SPECIAL" value-ref="productSpecialPopulator" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In my ProjectName-core.xml file, I added the attribute collection:

```
    <typegroup name="Product">
    <itemtype code="Product" autocreate="false" generate="false">
        <description>Pending description...</description>
        <attributes>
            <attribute qualifier="collection" type="java.lang.String">
                <description>Pending description...</description>
                <persistence type="property"></persistence>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
</typegroup>
```

But then, when I implemented the populator, I got the following error:

> Bound mismatch: The type TARGET is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter  of the type
>   AbstractProductPopulator

Here's the populator in question:

```
package de.hybris.electronics.facades.populators;

import de.hybris.electronics.facades.product.data.ProductData;
import de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.converters.populator.AbstractProductPopulator;
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.dto.converter.ConversionException;


public class ProductSpecialPopulator<SOURCE extends ProductModel, TARGET extends ProductData>
        extends AbstractProductPopulator<SOURCE, TARGET>
{


    @Override
    public void populate(final ProductModel source, final ProductData target) throws ConversionException
    {
        target.setCollection(source.getCollection());
    }

}
```

The error itself is thrown by TARGET in this line:

```
        extends AbstractProductPopulator<SOURCE, TARGET>
```

And here's the definition of the AbstractProductPopulator:

```
public abstract class AbstractProductPopulator<SOURCE extends ProductModel, TARGET extends ProductData>
        implements Populator<SOURCE, TARGET>
```

Comment: This `AbstractProductPopulator` is not something "public" can you post the class definition for it (ie. the line `public abstract class AbstractProductPopulator ...`)

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post to include the definition of the Abstract populator.

Comment: See the namespaces of the ProductData and the one in the AbstractProductPopulator.  They are probably different. I would recommend you to extend only ProductPopulator if you are with Hybris 6+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is caused by the fact that **ProductSpecialPopulator** uses **de.hybris.electronics.facades.product.data**.*ProductData*

and the **AbstractProductPopulator** most probably uses **de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data**.*ProductData*,

therefore these are two different classes(the package is different but the name, i.e ProductData is the same) causing the error.

Most probably there is an extensionName-beans.xml file in which the bean for ProductData is defined like this **class="de.hybris.electronics.facades.product.data.ProductData"** 
 instead of **class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData"**, which should be the proper way of adding an attribute to the already existing hybris Product Data

Comment: You're absolutely right. In electronicsfacades-beans.xml file, the collection bean's class was pointed at the wrong path. I changed it and the error disappeared after the build. Thanks a lot.